# Simple Linux CLI tool to dump Firefox bookmarks to stdout?

Tags: linux, firefox

Sometimes I would like to find a bookmarked URL for pasting it to a friend to Jabber (mcabber). Loading Firefox for that, then immediately closing it seems hugely overkill, I'd rather have a Linux CLI app that dumps all bookmarks to stdout and filter the results through grep. Of course, I can solve this by giving up completely on using bookmarks in Firefox and just save links to a simple text file, but I already have many ones.

Is there such a CLI app that can process a Firefox profile and dump bookmarks?

Should I instead aim to try automating somehow the export of Firefox bookmarks to a simpler (ideally plain text) format when it closes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sqlite3 places.sqlite "select moz_places.url, moz_bookmarks.title
                       from moz_places, moz_bookmarks
                       where moz_bookmarks.fk = moz_places.id
                       and moz_bookmarks.type = 1
                       and length(moz_bookmarks.title) > 0
                       order by moz_bookmarks.dateAdded"
```

*(Note: I suck at SQL.)*

Add `-line`, `-html`, `-separator " | "`, or `-separator $'\t'` for alternate output formats.

Answer (score 2):

The link below will automatically get you HTML and not plain text but it seems to work fine (I'm using 7.0.1) and you could probably use grep to parse out what you want.
http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2043-automatically-export-bookmarks-from-firefox

Which in a nutshell says to
use `about:config` (typed in the address bar) to set "browser.bookmarks.autoExportHTML" to true.

Update: I tried
  `grep -i http <PathToProfile>/bookmarks.html | awk '{print $2}'`
and got a nice listing of bookmarked pages.  This may take some tweaking and playing around but it works great.

Comment: `awk '/http/{print $2}`'

Comment: Man I wish I took the time to understand awk better. Everything I have ever seen amazes me but it has never tipped the scales of actually making time to learn it.

Answer (score 1):

FWIWI, I just came across https://github.com/zefr0x/foxmarks . I haven't tried it yet but it looks like it's exactly what OP asked for (12 years ago, admittedly).

Answer (score 0):

The booknarks are already in html-format (with additional information) in your ~/.mozilla/firefox/xyz.default/bookmarks.html (`xyz` is some other string in your directory).

Comment: My fresh install of Firefox (7.0.1) stores them in places.sqlite http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles and only exports them on demand unless you set it to do so automatically.

Comment: @Dennis: Where do you set it to do automatically?

Comment: @vtest: in `about:config` there is a key `browser.bookmarks.autoExportHTML`. Checkout the other keys containing `bookmark` too.